# When I try to install Trac on Windows I get an error when I need to create a project

Tags: python, trac

When I try to install Trac on Windows, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Python25\Scripts\trac-admin-script.py", line 5, in <module> from 
pkg_resources import load_entry_point   

File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 2565, in <module>      
parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()   

File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 524, in resolve     raise    
DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound:  
Trac==1.0.1
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be an env var path problem, not sure. I recommend to install the Windows version of [Bitnami Trac Stack](http://bitnami.com/stack/trac) because it's an all-in-one package of Apache+Python+SVN+Trac. You install in a 3-minutes-action by click-click-click-click-done approach, and you will not have any trouble.